# Wait until a webhook is triggered

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I would like to put something mid-pipeline that waits until a web hook is hit. Ideally, my pipeline will do something like:

1. Deploy to QA
2. Merge Request
3. Deploy to UAT
4. Deploy to Prod

I have the "Merge Request" stage create the merge request (in GitLab). That part is done. I now want to wait until the merge request is accepted before I move onto the next stage. I would love it to be a webhook.

I could write some code to poll the request, but I would like to avoid polling if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting around this by creating my merge request via the GitLab API.  Then polling that API and waiting for the status to be 'merged'.  I would much rather have a webhook to avoid polling.  But the `waitUntil` function slowly adds more time in between polls so it doesn't tax the system too much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a plugin that allows you to block job execution while waiting for a webhook.

I think a more straight forward approach would be to split your pipeline in two:

- QA + Merge Request
- UAT + Prod

The second pipeline can be configured to be triggered using the [GitLab plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin). As I understand it, you can follow [the example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#declarative-pipeline-syntax) in the `README.md` but your trigger should only fire when a push is made to the target branch e.g. if all of your merge-requests target `master`:

```
triggers {
    gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: false, branchFilterType: 'master')
}
```

The benefit here is that you're not tying up a slave while waiting for the webhook (which could take a while depending on the size of the changes in the Merge Request and who is reviewing them).

The only issue this raises is if you have to maintain state across the two playbooks. I've written pipelines before that use a unique sha in the name for related resources. In your scenario you would lose access to that variable in the second pipeline.

Comment: This is an option I considered, I appreciate your response but this is an extreme workaround and this is the last resort. 
I would rather poll the MR then break the pipeline into two.

Comment: If you get this working I'd love to hear more about it! I'll be keeping an eye on this thread, best of luck!

Comment: It's done, I didn't do what you suggested, read The other answer.  I am doing it a little different, message and and I'll explain.